# Colors not showing up on charts in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have an ionic project that uses charts and I have used a **chart.js** library.
If I provide dummy data to the chart then the chart shows the colours. Here is the code for it.

**home.ts**

```
public donutChartData: String[] = ["1100","1200","1300"];
public donutChartLabels: String[] = ["I","Me","Myself"];
public donutChartType: string = "doughnut"
```

**home.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
<canvas baseChart [data]='donutChartData' height="350" [labels]='donutChartLabels' [chartType]='donutChartType'>
</canvas>
```

But if I provide my customised data that is coming from odoo server, the chart shows in white colour. Here is the data that i have get from api in the console.

```
-------donutChartData------800,900,1000,1200,1500
-------donutChartLabels------01-Aug-2017,02-Aug-2017,03-Aug-2017,04-Aug-2017,05-Aug-2017
```

Here is the code for customised chart data.

**home.ts**

```
public donutChartData: String[] = [];
public donutChartLabels: String[] = [];
public donutChartType: string = "doughnut"

private display(): void {
    let model = "pedo.meter";
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    let id: number = data.partner_id;

    this.odooRpc
    .searchRead(
        model,
        this.domain,
        this.fields,
        this.limit,
        this.offset,
        this.sort
    )
    .then((res: any) => {
        let json = JSON.parse(res._body)["result"].records;

        let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.pedoChartData));
        let clone2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.doughnutChartColors));

        clone[0].data = [];
        clone2[0].backgroundColor = [];

        for (let i in json) {
        if (id === json[i].partner_id[0]) {
            let date = json[i].date;
            let latest_date: string = this.datePipe.transform(
            date,
            "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            );
            this.pedoChartLabels.push(latest_date);
            this.donutChartLabels.push(latest_date);

            clone[0].data.push(json[i].steps);
            clone2[0].backgroundColor.push(this.dynamicColors());
        }
        }
        this.donutChartData = clone[0].data;

        console.log("-------donutChartData------" + this.donutChartData);
        console.log("-------donutChartLabels------" + this.donutChartLabels);
        console.log("--------Json--------" + JSON.stringify(json));
    });
}
```

I googled a lot but can't get why it happens. please help me out Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, use [colors]="chartColors" in canvas**

**home.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
<canvas baseChart [data]='donutChartData' height="350" [labels]='donutChartLabels' [colors]="chartColors" [chartType]='donutChartType'>
</canvas>
```

**in home.ts create variable;**

```
  public chartColors: any[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor:["#FF7360", "#6FC8CE", "#8dd35f", "#2a80f7"]
    }];
```

Comment: but I have dynamic data.

Comment: Colors or data? Which is dynamic?

Comment: data is dynamic and according to data the colours must be dynamic

Comment: You can place the color in the variable by pulling it together with the data